# PHP variable variables getting array value

Tags: php, variable-variables

I'm building a condition check where I'm passing in the variable and a value to check.  In this case the variable is an array value, but I can't get it to return it correctly

```
//happens somewhere else
$specialFeature['option1']="on";
$specialFeature['option2']="on";
$specialFeature['option3']="off";

//what I'm trying to do
#query a db
$row = $result->fetch_array()
#results for purpose of demo
#$row['var'] = "specialFeature['option2']";
#$row['val'] = "on";
if($$row['var'] == $row['val']){
    //what i'm expecting
    echo "OK";
}
```

My issue is `$$var` is always null.  What am I doing wrong?  Is this possible?

Comment: why not you try like this simply call as $var = "$ARRAY['myKey3']";

Comment: `$val == $ARRAY['myKey3']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is "correct", but I got the result I was looking for by doing this:

```
//happens somewhere else
$specialFeature['option1']="on";
$specialFeature['option2']="on";
$specialFeature['option3']="off";

//what I'm trying to do
#query a db
$row = $result->fetch_array()
#results for purpose of demo
#$row['var'] = "specialFeature['option2']";
#$row['val'] = "on";

$var = $row['var'];

if (strpos($var,'[') !== false) {
    $varA = str_split($var,strpos($var,'['));
    $varA[1] = substr($varA[1],1,-1);
    if (strpos($varA[1],"'") !== false) {
        $varA[1] = substr($varA[1],1,-1);
    }
}

if(${$varA[0]}[$varA[1]] == $row['val']){
    //what i'm expecting
    echo "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//happens somewhere else
$ARRAY['myKey1']=1;
$ARRAY['myKey2']=2;
$ARRAY['myKey3']=3;

//what I'm trying to do
$var = "ARRAY['myKey3']";
$val = 3;
if(${$var} == $val){
    //what i'm expecting
    echo "OK";
}
```

From PHP.net:
In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write $$a[1] then the parser needs to know if you meant to use $a[1] as a variable, or if you wanted $$a as the variable and then the [1] index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1]} for the first case and ${$a}[1] for the second.

Edit:
The array-index seems to be the problem.

To split the variable name you could use something like

```
preg_match('/(.*)\[\'(.*)\'\]/', $row['var'], $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `$$var` you get following: `${"ARRAY['myKey3']"}`, so it is treated as a variable with name `ARRAY['myKey3']` (Which doesn't exist, though you can create it with `$$var = 'new value'`, but it will differ from `$ARRAY['myKey3']` as they will be 2 different variables). Probably you are looking for `if ($ARRAY['myKey3'] == $val)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ARRAY['myKey1']=1;
$ARRAY['myKey2']=2;
$ARRAY['myKey3']=3;

//what I'm trying to do
$var = "ARRAY";//pass variable name or array name
$val = 3;
if((${$var}['myKey3']) == $val){
    //what i'm expecting
    echo "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(${$var} == $val){
    //what i'm expecting
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: Tried that with no success

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
    $var = $ARRAY['myKey3'];
    $val = 3;
     if($var == $val){
     //what i'm expecting
     echo "OK";
           }
```

Comment: And yes you are doing something wrong. You are assigning a value to the  condition block, $$ for assigning a value that is equal to original  variable but condition is just for checking the value its true or false, for in this instance $$var is NULL so the condition is not true that's why its returning nothing. Just see what happened  with this code  var_dump($$var);